# Negative enchantments

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was thinking and I had a thought, if i gave my sword -1 knock-back would it fling the attacked towards me, away like usual or do nothing.

Or if I enchanted my bow with -1 punch, what would it do?

If I gave my armor negative thorns would it hurt me, heal the attacker or nothing, ect.

Comment: I Don't Think I Will Work!

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. When you go into the NBT file database, you can change the level, by inserting the level you want. The way it is accessed is that it puts the level like this: "enchantment.level.[level]". If it recognizes the level and the enchantment as useable, it converts it to something like "knockback V". If you put a different letter in, it will default to no enchantment. This includes the "-" character, so if you put -1 in it will come out as "enchantment.level.-1" which it cannot recognize, therefore nothing special happens when you use the sword.

It would be pretty cool, though! :D

Comment: about an hour ago, my friend told me he tried putting a negative punch on a bow and it pulled the zombie towards him, until his minecraft crashed.  But he said it wouldn't work in the new snapshot.

Comment: According to the Wiki, NBT supports negative numbers.  http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/NBT_format  @Blue_Dragon360, are you perhaps referring to a particular editor that edit's NBT files, and the limitations therein, as opposed to the actual file format?

Comment: @john Interesting... I must be incorrect, then. I was using NBTexplorer when I tried, and I did it on a knock back sword. I checked the wiki, but I must have missed that. Ingame, it showed as 'enchantment.level.-10' and it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but the item has to be made with /give and it has to be level 32768 or higher to be negative. Think of 32767 to be the highest, then going higher goes negative. So, if I used /give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {ench:[{id:16,lvl:32768,}]} the damage would be lower than usual. Hope this helps! **EDIT:** This only works in 1.8 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, not without a mod. The first thought would to change the value of the enchantment of your weapon or armor in the code of the world.  But even if the enchantment value is changed. The code is not programmed, as far as I know, to understand negative enchantments.

Answer (score -1):

I've tested an enchantment over max with the /give command. and it recognizes it and negative enchants DO work at 1.8+. so diamond sword with max+1 sharpness, it gets -1 dmg. So its like iron sword, but more durable. :-)