# Making a minecraft skeleton's bow have no damage and knockback

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been working on this for hours, but everything hasn't worked. I am making a minion that shoots health arrows, and heals you. However, if your health is extremely low and it shoots you, your health goes below 0 before you get healed. Also, if you are on a tall structure and it shoots you, you will get knocked off and die. Here is the command so far:

```
/give @p minecraft:spawn_egg 1 0 {display:{Name:"Spawn Moustaches Minion"},EntityTag:{id:"minecraft:skeleton",CustomName:"Moustaches Minion",CustomNameVisible:1,IsVillager:0,IsBaby:0,HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:bow",Count:1},{id:"minecraft:tipped_arrow",Count:32b,tag:{Potion:"minecraft:strong_healing"}}],ArmorItems:[{id:"minecraft:diamond_boots",Count:1b,tag:{ench:[{id:0,lvl:3}]}},{id:"minecraft:diamond_leggings",Count:1b,tag:{ench:[{id:0,lvl:3}]}},{id:"minecraft:diamond_chestplate",Count:1b,tag:{ench:[{id:0,lvl:3}]}},{id:"minecraft:skull",Damage:3,Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"Moustaches Minion"},SkullOwner:"moustacheswin"}}],ArmorDropChances:[0.085F,0.085F,0.085F,1.0F],Attributes:[{Name:skeleton.spawnReinforcements,Base:1.0F}]}}
```

Comment: So you are looking for a combination of bow and arrow that delivers no damage or knockback.  I am not aware of anyway to eliminate knockback that way.  You might be able to use [CustomPotionEffects](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Arrow#Data_values) with instant health to work around the damage dealt, but I have not tested that.

Comment: Is "minecraft:strong_healing" a real tag? Have you tried something other than shooting?

Answer (score 0):

With a bow, the power level adds a fixed amount of dmg (2 i think and then each level gives an extra half heart - so a bow with level 9 power does 7 dmg.

According to the thread at the end, in at least some prior versions, enchantments with levels at 32768 or higher would be level -1 and beyond enchantments, so if you put the level at around 32800 you should start getting a mildly 'negative' damage arrow.  I can't say that negative damage is going to amount to healing, but if you got the arrow to at least zero damage then you would have what you are after.

[Negative enchantments](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/158518/negative-enchantments)